# Como embutir CSS nas tags do HTML?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc

Tenho um arquivo CSS contendo o seguinte código.

```
.texto{

Color: Red;

}
```

Tenho o arquivo HTML com essas *tags*:

```
<html>
<body>

<span class="texto">TEXTO 1<span>
<span class="texto">TEXTO 2<span>
<span class="texto">TEXTO 3<span>

<body>
</html>
```

Como faço para embutir o código CSS em todas as tags que tiver a classe `.texto` de modo automático?

Exemplo:

```
<html>
<body>

<span class="texto" style="Color: Red;">TEXTO 1<span>
<span class="texto" style="Color: Red;">TEXTO 2<span>
<span class="texto" style="Color: Red;">TEXTO 3<span>

<body>
</html>
```

Preciso para enviar e-mail com HTML formatado.

Comment: Correção. Pessoal desculpa, eu não mencionei que eu uso ASP.NET MVC C#. Possivelmente deve ter algo do lado do servidor que possa faz isso diretamente na View quando ela for carregada. Só que eu procurei mas não encontrei uma solução pratica.

Comment: Mencionou sim. Está nas *tags*. http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/297/quando-se-deve-colocar-o-nome-da-linguagem-no-t%C3%ADtulo/1911#1911

Answer (score 5):

Alguns programas de email se dão bem com CSS declarado no próprio HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    .texto {
        color: red;
     }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<span class="texto">TEXTO 1<span>
<span class="texto">TEXTO 2<span>
<span class="texto">TEXTO 3<span>

<body>
</html>
```

Porém é provável que certas coisas só funcionem com o atributo `style` *inline* em cada elemento, como você colocou na pergunta. Nesse caso não há solução simples, geralmente é o caso de fazer manualmente mesmo. Lembrando que CSS em email é sempre sujeito a falhas (certos programas de email aceitam algumas propriedades, outros não).

Comment: Concordo, utilizo CSS declarado no próprio CSS e não tenho problema. E fica mais fácil para um possível suporte futuro.

Answer (score 3):

Existe um projeto muito interessante no [GitHub](https://github.com/milkshakesoftware/PreMailer.Net) chamado PreMailer.Net da autoria de Martin H. Normark para lidar precisamente com este assunto:

> Biblioteca em C# para mover CSS para atributos de estilo *inline*, de forma a ganhar o máximo de compatibilidade com os clientes de e-mail.

**Exemplo:**

```cs
string htmlSource = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\caminho\para\email.html");

var result = PreMailer.MoveCssInline(htmlSource);

result.Html         // HTML com o CSS já no atributo `style`.
result.Warnings     // string[] com os eventuais erros durante o processamento.
```

O Blog a falar sobre este projeto:

### [Colocar CSS inline em C# e ASP.NET usando PreMailer.Net](http://martinnormark.com/move-css-inline-premailer-net/)

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando jquery vc pode fazer o seguinte:

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('.texto').css('color', 'red');
  });
</script>

<body>
  <span class="texto">TEXTO 1<span>
<span class="texto">TEXTO 2<span>
<span class="texto">TEXTO 3<span>
<body>
</html>
```

Desse jeito, ele fará com que a tag style seja carregada dentro do span quando a pagina for carregada.

Comment: Mas ele está falando de email! Ninguém vai deixar esse jQuery rodar dentro de uma mensagem de email.

Comment: Valeu pela resposta. Mas eu não posso usar scripts no envio de e-mail porque os clientes de email não deixa executar os scripts. Pelo menos eu tentei e não funcionou.

Comment: [Faltou mais jQuery](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif).

Comment: @Zuul Você ganhou a Internet hoje!

Answer (score 1):

Olá,
Antes de enviar o texto por email, prepare-o o texto para envio, segue um pequeno exemplo com Jquery:

```js
$( "#prepareToSend" ).one( "click", function() {
  $("[class=texto]").css( "color", "red" );
});
```

```css
.texto{
  color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="texto">email</p>

<button id="prepareToSend">Prepara html para enviar</button>
```

Como o Zull postou, tem o Projeto Premailer.net: Instale via Nuget (Package Manager Console):

```
PM> Install-Package PreMailer.net
```

Veja o uso no controller:

```
        public ActionResult TesteEmail()
    {
        string htmlFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:Emails\teste.html");

        var htmlToEmail = PreMailer.Net.PreMailer.MoveCssInline(htmlFile,true);// true para remover a tag style do html dps de copiar os estilos para tags no atributo syle:

        return Content(htmlToEmail.Html);
    }
```

Pelo que pude ver nesta biblioteca, é que ele só move o css para style inline se a mesma estiver na prória pagina html:
- *Entrada:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Teste</title>
<style>
    .well {background-color: #f5f5f5;}
    .text-success {color: green;}
    .text-center {text-align: center;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="well">
    <h1 class="text-center text-success">Hello World</h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Saida do `Content(htmlToEmail.Html);`:

```
<div class="well" style="background-color: #f5f5f5">
<h1 class="text-center text-success" style="text-align: center;color: green">Hello World</h1>
</div>
```

dei uma lida rápida também neste artigo:
http://chrispebble.com/inlining-a-css-stylesheet-with-c/

Comment: [Faltou mais jQuery](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif), afinal o navegador é quem envia os emails e não o servidor.

Answer (score 1):

Olá alguns servidores de email não dão suporte ao CSS, somente inline
visite esse site http://beaker.mailchimp.com/inline-css 
que faz a conversão do seu html para CSS inline

Comment: A ideia é boa, mas a "venda" da mesma carece alguma atenção: "_faz a conversão do seu html para CSS_" ?